# What is the best way to make text that has html translatable?

Tags: localization

I have a block of text I'd like to make translatable. Within that block of text there is a link.

The following works:

```
{{ "Lorem ipsum. <a href='{url}' target='_blank'>Aenean commodo ligula</a> eget dolor."|t({
    url: "#"
})|raw }}
```

But doesn't feel like the best way to do it as the translation file now requires HTML:

```
craft/translations/en_us.php

<?php

return array(
    "Lorem ipsum. <a href='{url}' target='_blank'>Aenean commodo ligula</a> eget dolor." => "Lorem ipsum. <a href='{url}' target='_blank'>Aenean commodo ligula</a> eget dolor."
);
```

Are there any other ways to do this that lead to a better separation of translatable text and HTML that relates to how the translator can interact with that text?

Comment: If you find a better way, let us know.  That's how we do it in the handful of places strings that need translating that have markup in them.

Answer (score 1):

You can move those HTML parts to parameters themselves.

**Template:**

```
{{ 'Lorem ipsum. {linkTagBegin}Aenean commodo ligula{linkTagEnd} eget dolor.'|t({
    linkTagBegin: '<a href="#" target="_blank">',
    linkTagEnd: '</a>'
})|raw }}
```

**Translation PHP file:**

```php
<?php

return [
    'Lorem ipsum. {linkTagBegin}Aenean commodo ligula{linkTagEnd} eget dolor.' => 'EN Lorem ipsum. {linkTagBegin}EN Aenean commodo ligula{linkTagEnd} EN eget dolor.'
];
```

**Result (bold part is the link):**

> EN Lorem ipsum. **EN Aenean commodo ligula** EN eget dolor.

So in the end the HTML is part of template file.